# Android client server using Games API

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm trying to figure out the best way to authenticate a user on both an Android game and the server hosting the game logic.

Currently I'm logging the user in using the `BaseGameUtils` package found in the google play games example files as described here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init

There doesn't seem to be a way to get a `id_token` to send to the server to authenticate the user so I use the `Games.getGamesServerAuthCode()` function to obtain an authcode and send the authcode to the server component. The server then exchanges the authcode for a token... But now I'm confused...

The server now has a token but the token expires. Is it expected to let the android app know the authcode was used to obtain a token and have the client issue a new authcode after it has expired?  Do I use the access token to facilitate a session between the client and server? Or do I just use the authcode process for "login" and issue my own token process between the android app and the server?

Thanks in advance!